# (LMAX disruptor)How to get data by myself not by callback?

Tags: java, lmax

i learn that LMAX disruptor is a  High Performance Inter-Thread Messaging Library.
But when i try to use it ,i found that the eventhandler use a callback method to process the data.

```
void onEvent(T event,
       long sequence,
       boolean endOfBatch)
         throws java.lang.Exception
```

Called when a publisher has published an event to the RingBuffer

But if i don't use callback to get data, i write a while(true) to get data by my self, what should i do ?

thanks!

Comment: Your question isn't all that clear - what are you trying to achieve?  What do you mean by your "own method"?

Comment: @Paolo, i don't want to use callback way to get data, i want use while(true) to get data, what should i do? thanks.

Comment: You should write your callback so it pushes the event into a queue. You can then loop over the queue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should write your callback so it pushes the event into a queue. You can then iterate over the queue.

```
Queue<Event> queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue(10);

void onEvent(Event event,
        long sequence,
        boolean endOfBatch)
        throws java.lang.Exception {
    queue.add(event);
}

public void test() {
    for ( Event event : queue ) {
        // Your stuff here.
    }
}
```

Comment: would this way will slow down the process speed?

Comment: @davidzhao - Of course it could - if you need maximum speed go to the bare metal and use the callback - if you need to do some flim-flam like this on it you have to expect a downside. That said - there shouldn't be much speed hit - probably unmeasurable.